# Two Tables relation with a WHERE clause condition if exists or not exists

Tags: mysql, sql

the query is

```
$query = "SELECT a.title, a.content, SUM(b.rating) as rating FROM posts a, ratings b WHERE a.id = :id AND a.id = b.pid GROUP BY b.author ORDER BY rating";
```

depends on these table

```
                 posts                                       ratings
  [ id  -  title   -   content -  author ]            [ pid  -  rating  -  author ]
   --------------------------------------              ---------------------------
  [ 1  -  title1  -  content1 -  author1 ]            [  1    -   8   -   author1 ]
  [ 2  -  title1  -  content2 -  author2 ]            [  1    -   5   -   author1 ]
  [ 3  -  title1  -  content4 -  author3 ]            [  1    -   9   -   author2 ]
  [ 4  -  title4  -  content4 -  author4 ]            [  1    -   6   -   author4 ]
  [ 5  -  title5  -  content5 -  author5 ]            [  5    -   3   -   author5 ]
```

Now i'm trying to `ORDER` posts by the `SUM` of all the ratings `WHERE` the `a.id = b.pid AND a.author = b.author` But it doesnt work ordered as it is supposed to be, And if there is no rating at all, the entire query values become empty since the clause `WHERE a.id = p.id` is empty, And i want to make it as a SUM = 0, How can i fix this exactly?

It is supposed to shows values like this if the `id` is `1` when `echo`ed

```
author1, author2, author4
```

but instead it just shows at randomized `ORDER` and if the ratings table is empty, no values are called at all.

Comment: Edity our question and show the results that you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax.

It is a little difficult to figure out what you want.  But you seem to have a big focus on authors, even though authors play a minimal role in your query.  This is what you are describing:

```
SELECT p.author, SUM(r.rating) as sumrating
FROM posts p LEFT JOIN
     ratings r
     ON p.id = r.pid AND p.author = r.author
WHERE a.id = :id 
GROUP BY p.author
ORDER BY sumrating;
```

It doesn't seem particularly useful to me.